# Android match_parent not working as expected layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view, android-scrollview

I have a custom view, `TriggerView`. When I override `onDraw` in the view, I draw a graph that sometimes overflows outside the viewable bounds of the view. So I want to embed the view inside a `ScrollView` so that the graph can be scrollable.

Here's my code without any `ScrollViews`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.roberts.croberts.mantis.ShotTriggerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.roberts.croberts.mantis.TriggerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/triggerView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        ...

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

See how in this screenshot that the triggerView fills all the remaining screen space:

[image: Screenshot]

So then I try to embed it in a ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.roberts.croberts.mantis.TriggerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/triggerView" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And then the TriggerView height gets shrunk to 0. I've tried every variation of `match_parent` and `wrap_content` I can think up, and can't get it to work:

[image: Screenshot]

edit - another interesting thing I just found is when I remove the container `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` and just have the `TriggerView`:

```
<com.roberts.croberts.mantis.TriggerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/triggerView"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Then the design tab says that the parent class is a `ScrollView`?:

[image: TriggerView (ScrollView)]

Comment: without showing what you are overriding in `onDraw` and maybe measure-related methods you may get 'blind shot' answers only... you have also in your code `<LinearLayout android:layout_height="0dp"` and inside your custom view, so it is obvious it have same height...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.roberts.croberts.mantis.TriggerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/triggerView" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Some issues here:
`ScrollView` with height defined as match_parent has no sense - it always should be set to wrap_content.
`LinearLayout` height is set to match_parent what is also wrong, as this element should define height of containing `ScrollView` - change it to wrap_content.
End last - your custom view - it also should have height set to wrap_content (or some fixed value). If it still doesn't work well, look for issues inside this view - hard to say - inflated layout, or `onMeasure()` method

Comment: and there is also `android:fillViewport` attr, may be usefull. [CHECK](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Comment: The biggest trick that I needed was just to override the `onMeasure()` method

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a custom view. Please post the view class. The custom must be overriding onDraw and onMeasure method and doing something differently there.